# Finding the uncertainty of a value after taking the average

Tags: measurements, error-analysis, data-analysis

Recently I did a measurement experiment where I measured the diameter of a piece of wire using a micrometer. I tested it 4 times. I got 0.87, 0.89, 0.90,0.90 respectively. The units being millimeter. My micrometer has a least count of 0.05mm. The uncertainty of a single measurement would then be plus or minus 0.05mm. However how would I express the uncertainty after taking the average of the 4 values I stated above. Would it still be plus or minus 0.05mm? Or what could it be?
I'm slightly confused.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57317/